# Using animate.css library for nuxt page transitions

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to use the animate.css library for nuxt page transtions but it doesnt seem to be working. I added the animate.css to the nuxt.config.js and loads in fine. But when try to use one of the transition names, nothing happens.
Tried:

```
transition: 'bounceInUp'
```

and also:

```
transition: {name:'bounceInUp',type:'animation'}
```

no animations (or errors) on page load by either.

EDIT:
Tried adding in custom active classes. Still nothing.

Full Page Code:

```
<template>
  <v-layout>
    <v-flex class="text-center">
      <blockquote class="blockquote">
        Testing amination page
      </blockquote>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    transition: {name:'bc',type:'animation'}
  }
</script>

<style>

.bc-enter-active {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceInUp;
    animation-name: bounceInUp
}
.bc-leave-active {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceInUp;
    animation-name: bounceOutUp
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided you already have animate.css installed.

*nuxt.config.js*

```
css: ['animate.css/animate.compat.css'],
```

Vue file. Just a minor tweak with what you already have.

```
<script>
  export default {
    transition: {name:'bc'}
  }
</script>
<style>
.bc-enter-active {
    animation: bounceInUp 5s;
}
.bc-leave-active {
    animation: bounceOutUp 5s;
}
</style>
```

[This](https://youtu.be/kq-IWxvxams?t=1074) helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to define `-enter-active` and `-leave-active` classes for the same animation name in CSS. Such as:

```css
. bounceInUp-enter-active {
  animation: bounceInUp .8s;
}
. bounceInUp-leave-active {
  animation: bounceInUp .5s;
}
```

Comment: So there would be no way to use the animate.css library for page animations in nuxt? Why cant i use keyframes? Regular vuejs transitions allow keyframes

Comment: Edited with custom active classes still nothing